# Drawing a line between two points with text

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to use the functionality of the measure tool to display a line with text next to it like in the following picture:

[image]

I don't want to copy code from the measure extension. Does the viewer have this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exposed through the public API unfortunately. You could take a look at how this feature is implemented in the viewer3D.js source, I don't see why you couldn't *"copy code from the measure extension"* ...

Another suggestion would be to use three.js to draw the lines and svg to overlay 2D graphics, you can find examples in those extensions:

[Viewing.Extension.BoundingBox](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/tree/master/src/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.BoundingBox)

[Viewing.Extension.Markup3D](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/tree/master/src/Viewing.Extension.Markup3D)